# MySql: lock only one table for read/write

Tags: php, mysql

I need to lock a specific table for read and write, but i don't want to lock the other tables of the database.

In this case, i'm trying to save a row in 'users' table, and another process is trying to make a query on 'tasks' table, but when applies lock write on 'users' table, the other process can't make this query.

First request:

```
$db = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$result = $db->query("LOCK TABLES users WRITE;");
sleep(15);
$result = $db->query("UNLOCK TABLES;");
```

Second request in parallel:

```
$db = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tasks;");
```

Is there any trick to do here?

Comment: Hey, just too rule out other possibilities... if you comment out the queries in the first request (but let the sleep in). Does the second work instantly? (just asking because an other reason to your problem could be that only 1 request can run in parallel. )

Comment: That doesn't sound like what LOCK _TABLES_ ought to be doing. What database engine are you using?

Comment: The second request to database is called by another client. But cannot read any table. sleep() was just used to emulate a process running by the first client.

Comment: I'm using InnoDB.

Comment: I put your code in 2 php files and then requested both. The second one did not wait for the first. It looks like `look tables` is not causing a problem in the given code. (using innoDB as well. 10.1.34-MariaDB)  Could you add more information so that we can reproduce it?